# How to find a optimal center for a bounding sphere of a convex set

Tags: geometry, non-convex-optimization

I have a special convex set which is a hypersphere sliced by every hyperplane vertical to every axis. Is there an analytical or approximated method for obtaining the shape's bounding sphere which minimizes its radius? For instance, in 2d case, solving the bounding circle of the green part.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGrrp.png)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Sergio I formed it as a min-max problem and found the inner part maximizing a convex function on a convex set. I even do not know how to calculate the inner part for a given center.